# Meaning of adjusted correlation coefficient

Tags: regression, correlation, goodness-of-fit

It is well-known that for simple linear regression, $R^2 = \rho^2$, where $$R^2 = 1-\frac{\sum (y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}{\sum (y_i - \mu_y)^2}$$
and $$\rho = \frac{\sum (y_i-\mu_y)(\hat{y}_i-\mu_{\hat{y}})}{\sqrt{\sum (y_i-\mu_y)^2 \times \sum \left(\hat{y}_i-\mu_{\hat{y}}\right)^2}}.$$

I'm interested in the relationship in more general contexts, where $\hat{y}_i$ is not necessarily a simple linear regression model trained on $y_i$.

I've shown that, with no assumptions on $\hat{y}_i$, we have $$R^2 = \rho^2 - \frac{\beta^2}{\sigma_y^2}-\frac{(\alpha+\beta^2)^2}{\sigma_y^2\sigma_{\hat{y}}^2},$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
\alpha &= \frac{1}{N}\sum (y_i-\hat{y}_i)(\hat{y}_i-\mu_y),\\
\beta &= \mu_y - \mu_{\hat{y}}
\end{aligned}$$
The quantities $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are closely related to error derivatives with respect to the slope and intercept (respectively) in a simple regression model, so in this context they vanish (leading to $R^2 = \rho^2$).

In more general contexts (such as regression models with a held-out test set), both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be non-vanishing. Of course $\beta$ measures the mean error, while $\alpha$ measures an error in the model coefficients (i.e., we would have $\alpha = 0$ had the model seen the test set during training).

So, my questions is: in a context where an error in the mean is unimportant but errors in the coefficients are important, is it reasonable to use either of the following two adjust goodness-of-fit metrics?
$$\begin{aligned}
\rho^2_{\text{adj},1} &= \rho^2 - \frac{(\alpha+\beta^2)^2}{\sigma^2_y \sigma^2_{\hat{y}}}\\
\rho^2_{\text{adj},2} &= \rho^2 - \frac{\alpha^2}{\sigma^2_y \sigma^2_{\hat{y}}}
\end{aligned}$$
(that is, dropping the leading-order $\beta$ term or dropping all $\beta$ terms). Better yet, is there a name or a reference for either of these quantities?